# Setting width and height to child of GridView not working

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set a custom width and height to the children of a `GridView`. I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      children: coolArray.map((String currentItem) {
        return Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
          width: 17,
          height: 10,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('currentItem'),
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
```

The items have their own height which I don't know how they're calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use childAspectRatio, example

```
  GridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 5,
  childAspectRatio:width/height,
  children: coolArray.map((String currentItem) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('currentItem'),
    );
  }).toList());
```

Comment: How can I get the crossAxisCount to auto layout based on screen width?